# Pulling the third number out of a a + b + c = d string

Tags: java, string, math, numbers

What I mean is if I have a string such as `23 + 4 + 13 = 40` or `123 - 100 + 245 = 268` how would I get the third (c) part out of the string? In the case of the examples, I want to get the `13` or the `245` out to use.

How would I go about doing so?

Here's the code I have so far to get the first number, operator, second number, and answer from the problems, but I'm unsure of how to get the third number.

```
int first = Integer.parseInt(fileContent.substring(0, fileContent.indexOf(" ")));
char operator = getOperator(fileContent);
int second = secondNumber(result, fileContent);
int last = Integer.parseInt(result.substring(result.indexOf("=") + 1));
```

I cannot use arrays, regex, try/catch, or systemTokenizers for this.

Update: This is for a lab I have to do, but I can't use any of those things because it's meant to be an "introductory" course and we're not supposed to know about them yet. Very inconvenient.

This is my getOperator method

```
public static char getOperator(String fileContent){


    int checkAdd = fileContent.indexOf('+');
    int checkMinus = fileContent.indexOf('-');
    int checkMulti = fileContent.indexOf('*');
    int checkDivi = fileContent.indexOf('/');

    if (checkAdd != -1){
        char operator = fileContent.charAt(fileContent.indexOf('+')); 
        return operator;
    }   
    else if (checkMinus != -1) {
       char operator = fileContent.charAt(fileContent.indexOf('-'));
       return operator;
    }
    else if (checkMulti != -1) {
        char operator = fileContent.charAt(fileContent.indexOf('*'));
        return operator;
    }
    else if (checkDivi != -1){
        char operator = fileContent.charAt(fileContent.indexOf('/'));
        return operator;
    }
    return ' ';
```

and this is my secondNumber method:

```
public static double secondNumber(String result, String opContent){

    int checkAdd = opContent.indexOf('+');
    int checkMinus = opContent.indexOf('-');
    int checkMulti = opContent.indexOf('*');
    int checkDivi = opContent.indexOf('/');

    if (checkAdd != -1){
        return Double.parseDouble(result.substring(result.indexOf('+')+1 , result.indexOf('='))); 
    }   
    else if (checkMinus != -1) {
        return Double.parseDouble(result.substring(result.indexOf('-')+1 , result.indexOf('='))); 
    }
    else if (checkMulti != -1) {
        return Double.parseDouble(result.substring(result.indexOf('*')+1 , result.indexOf('='))); 
    }
    else if (checkDivi != -1){
        return Double.parseDouble(result.substring(result.indexOf('/')+1 , result.indexOf('='))); 
    }
    return 0;   
}
```

result comes from this method:

```
public static String removeSpaces(String content){
    String result = content.replace(" ","");
    return result;
}
```

Comment: can you use a `Scanner` ?

Comment: do you have a finite list of all the possible operators (e.g. +,-,/,* etc.) ?  if yes, you could use regex to delimit your string into an array(list) by the finite list of operators

Comment: Why can't you use regex or tokenizers?  is this homework?

Comment: since you have the first, second number and the first operator, replace the first occurrence of both for "", then you use the getOperator again and again the Integer.parseInt(fileContent.substring(0, fileContent.indexOf(" ")));

Comment: The problems are actually in a file that is being scanned in, so they're not really static.

Comment: It might be useful to show your `getOperator` and `secondNumber` methods. I have trouble imagining code in which you can get a, b, and d but not c from that sort of string.

Comment: Assuming the pattern is always a + b + c = d,  could you use String.lastIndexOf('+') and String.indexOf('=') to isolate c ?

Comment: @k2col I'll try it and see if it works.

Comment: where the `result` comes from?

Comment: result is just a line in a method that does a .replace(" " , "") to remove white space

Comment: @k2col It doesn't quite work, especially if the operators aren't the same. Like if a + b - c = d. As is right now, it returns an error.

Answer (score 1):

A good way to do this (within your restrictions) is to use the [`String.indexOf` overload](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) that takes a `fromIndex`, and a method to do something like that, but for operators:

```
public static int getNextOperatorIndex(String fileContent, int startIndex)
{
    for (int i = startIndex; i < fileContent.length(); i++)
    {
        if (fileContent.charAt(i) == '+' ||
            fileContent.charAt(i) == '-' ||
            fileContent.charAt(i) == '*' ||
            fileContent.charAt(i) == '/')
            return i;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

With these two methods, you can get the indexes that split your string apart:

```
int firstOperatorIndex = getNextOperatorIndex(fileContent, 0);
int secondOperatorIndex = getNextOperatorIndex(fileContent,firstOperatorIndex+1);
int equalsIndex = fileContent.indexOf("=", secondOperatorIndex);
```

Since this is homework, I'll leave the last part to you:

```
//TODO: get a, b, c, d, and both operators based on those indexes
```

You can use [`String.trim()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim%28%29) or `replace` (e.g. `fileContent = fileContent.replace(" ", "");`) to eliminate whitespace more easily.

Comment: I have another question. Is there a way that I can check if there is a second operator so that I can go between two (a+b=c) and three(a+b-c=d) problems?

Comment: Yes, if `secondOperatorIndex` is `-1`, then there's no second operator.

Answer (score 0):

The problem has 3 parts: tokenizing, semantic typing, and selection. Tokenizing, or lexical analysis, is collecting individual characters into meaningful groups: whitespace, numbers and operators in your problem. The semantic typing is recognizing the tokens as meaningful elements of the expression. Converting the string of digits to a number, determining the specific operation. If you are writing an expression compiler, these would go into your Abstract Syntax Tree (AST), but your problem is to find (select) the third numeric element.

To solve, implement each part. The tokenizer will iterate through your source string and return tokens. What you want is a class that will take the input string as a constructor parameter, and have a method that will return the next token each time it is called. This is what the java tokenizer offers.

The type recognizer will receive a token and return a container class that contains the type of the token and its value.  In an AST this is called a node. If the node is a number, it contains the integer value. If it is an operator, the value should be an enum that identifies the operation.

Feed that into a class that finds the third number node.

Given the restrictions on the implementation, this sounds like homework. There is enough here to get you started. If it is not homework, please explain why the restrictions are in place.

There is an excellent tool called ANTLR that solves this kind of problem. It is a parser generator and creates lexical and semantic analyzers from a grammar.  If you have to do a lot of this kind of challenge, it is worth knowing.

Answer (score 0):

This makes a lot of assumptions, first, you can implement your own "Tokenizer", second, if you call `nextInt()`, the next token has to be an int. It does what you want, have fun playing with it, debug, see how it works, understand the algorithm.

```
public static class PoorManTokenizer {

    private String content;

    public PoorManTokenizer(String fileContent) {
        this.content = fileContent.trim();
    }

    public char nextChar() {
        return next().charAt(0);
    }

    public int nextInt() {
        return Integer.parseInt(next());
    }

    private String next() {
        int indexOf = content.indexOf(" ");
        if (indexOf == -1) {
            indexOf = content.length();
        }
        String substring = content.substring(0, indexOf);
        content = content.substring(substring.length()).trim();
        return substring;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    String fileContent = "23 + 4 + 13 = 40";

    PoorManTokenizer poorManTokenizer = new PoorManTokenizer(fileContent);

    int firstNumber = poorManTokenizer.nextInt();
    char firstOperator = poorManTokenizer.nextChar();
    int secondNumber = poorManTokenizer.nextInt();
    char secondOperator = poorManTokenizer.nextChar();
    int thirdNumber = poorManTokenizer.nextInt();
    char thirdOperator = poorManTokenizer.nextChar();
    int lastNumber = poorManTokenizer.nextInt();

}
```